# Обработка касаний, определить расположение пальцев относительно друг друга

Tags: android, touch

Допустим дан двухмерный массив с координатами прикосновения всех пяти пальцев. Порядок касания пальцев хаотичен. Как отсортировать массив, чтобы пальцы шли по порядку, от большого к мизинцу, или от мизинца к большому?

Comment: сходу вопрос, а как будет определяться правая рука или левая?

Comment: А если коснулись тремя пальцами одной руки и двумя другой? А если пять разных людей коснулись одним пальцем? Так что, думаю, что никак.

Comment: обязательным условием будет, касание правой рукой, и всеми 5 пальцами.

Comment: Ну тогда по х координате смотрите. Самая минимальная - большой, следующая - указательный и т.д.

Comment: @eugeneek хотел предложить этот вариант - но большой палец с мизинцем могут по x координате (жесть то как звучит) путаться с другими пальцами...

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky просто нужно добавить обязательным условием, чтобы не путались =)) А вообще странная немного задача у ТС. Если можно ставить какие-то обязательные условия пользователям, почему бы тогда не сказать им каким пальцем и когда тыкать.

Comment: Ну в принципе, мне даже не сколько порядок нужен, а расстояние между ближайшими пальцами, для первоначальной настройки приложения под руку пользователя.